# Group by gives error "Invalid use of group function"

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'd like to get the number of likes each user got from the following tables:

- **Users table**: contains the userid, email, contact no
- **Like table**:  which contains picture ids, and userids who liked it
- **Picture posted table***: contains picture ids, user id who posted it

I am using the following query which is giving the error "Invalid use of group function":

```
select sum(count(pid)) from p_like where pid in (
        select pid from p_picuser where userid in (
            SELECT userid from p_users 
            )
        ) GROUP BY pid
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the schema as `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result for that sample data. You should also post the error message.

Comment: It errors out because it doesn't make sense.  What does the sum of the count of the group column even mean?????

Answer (score 0):

You can't aggregate (sums, counts, etc) the same variables on which you're grouping by.  If you'd like counts by user, group on that.  So maybe try something like:

```
SELECT userid, count(*) from p_like GROUP BY user
```

to get the like-count's by userId from your `p_like` table.   Strictly-speaking, this your answer.

To add more user details then, you can make that a sub-query and join to you p_user table, e.g.

```
SELECT email, like_count from p_users pusers, (
    SELECT userid, count(*) like_cound from p_like GROUP BY user
   ) group_sub
WHERE p_users.userid = group_sub.userid
```